Avoid container image from exiting in net aspire
I am using builder.AddPostgres().WithImage(...) but the image has this behaviour of exiting if I don't use -it when doing docker run
this is the way the documentation says to use this image:
docker run \
    -it \
    -v postgresml_data:/var/lib/postgresql \
    -p 5433:5432 \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    ghcr.io/postgresml/postgresml:2.7.12 \
    sudo -u postgresml psql -d postgresml

this is how I add postgres but does not seed to work, the item is show in the dashboard as exited and in docker if I press the play button it just start and exit in less than a minute, which is the correct way to keep the container running.
    postgres = builder.AddPostgres("lcommerce-dependecy-postgres", port: 5432)
        .WithImage("postgresml/postgresml")
        .WithImageTag("2.9.3")
        .WithImageRegistry("ghcr.io")
        .WithHttpEndpoint(name: "endpoint-55432-5432",
            port: 8000, targetPort: 8000, isProxied: true)
        .WithContainerRuntimeArgs("-it", "--gpus=all");


I tried to keep the container running using .WithContainerRuntimeArgs("-it", "--gpus=all") but keep exiting. (by default net aspire adds postgres user and password I already tested another image pgvector/pgvector and it works fine but this one does no exit by default)
UPDATE
YOU CAN USE
.WithContainerRuntimeArgs("-i", "--gpus=all")
.WithArgs("sudo", "-u", "postgresml", "psql", "-d", "postgresml")

BUT BEST IS
(as the answer suggest):
.WithContainerRuntimeArgs("--gpus=all")
.WithArgs( "sleep","infinity")

THE CORRECT IS
Create a custom image with the extension and needed modules and set the database server as the main persistent process instead of using a workaround (as the answer mentioned)

@HansKilian I was able to keep it running with the combination:
.WithContainerRuntimeArgs("-i", "--gpus=all").WithArgs("sudo", "-u", "postgresml", "psql", "-d", "postgresml")
if I combined all in
.WithContainerRuntimeArgs("-i", "--gpus=all", "sudo", "-u", "postgresml", "psql", "-d", "postgresml")
I get this strange error (it creates a erroneous format I think):
'Unable to find image 'sudo:latest' locally\nError response from daemon: pull access denied for sudo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'\n'

I think DavidMaze's suggestion to use .WithArgs is the way to go. That's why I deleted my comment.

That image's Dockerfile is publicly available.  It has a couple of significant design issues.  Most notably, it does not run the database server as the main container process, but instead depends on some other process running to "keep the container alive", something you should never need to actually do.  A typical hackaround for this is to run a meaningless sleep command.  This probably looks something like
postgres = builder.AddPostgres("lcommerce-dependecy-postgres", port: 5432)
  .WithArgs("sleep", "infinity")
  ...;


What's happening internally?  The image declares
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]

(typically you should just run script, not bash script) without a default CMD.  The entrypoint.sh  calls service postgresql start (service doesn't usually work in Docker and a container normally only runs one process), runs several sudo -u postgresml commands (sudo is hard to use and is almost always unnecessary in Docker) and finally ends with
exec "$@"

Docker passes the CMD as arguments to the ENTRYPOINT, but in the default setup CMD is empty.  That runs exec with no arguments, which does nothing, and the script exits.  Since the script is the main container process, when the script exits, the container exits too.
The Docker Hub postgres image page points at the PostGIS image as a more typical way of building a PostgreSQL image plus an extension.  Download the extension proper (the PostgresML Dockerfile uses APT to get it, which should be just fine), put the relevant SQL CREATE EXTENSION commands into a script in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, and let the normal first-time initialization set up the extension.  For this particular extension you'd need to add CUDA on top of a PostgreSQL image rather than vice versa, but the standard database image setup is kind of involved and it could be better to reuse it.

delete the .withCommand("sleep", "infinity") because WithCommand has another way to define it in the net aspire context link (I know is just an example but it can create confussion) and I will accept the answer.

I have been studying more the image an repository so I will be able to get all the capabilities and not just the extension pmgl which is kind of unsusable without the other parts (dashboard, models, download and trainning) for machine learning purpose, your answer show me the path to create a custom image with better design.

I think the .NET Aspire .WithArgs() extension is the right setting?

To be honest I try to use all combinations .WithArgs(...) .WithContainerRuntimeArgs(...) to be able to use "sleep", "infinity" or even bin\bash -c "sleep infinity" (I did not try to use .WithCommand(...) because I dont want to create another resource). In net aspire each space in a command needs to be separated in individual strings and I couldn't find out how to be able to use sleep infinity it generates me a format error, the only thing that works right now is .WithArgs("sudo", "-u", "postgresml", "psql", "-d", "postgresml")

but as I mentioned the way correct is to create a custom image with better design (running the database server daemon as the main process) as you suggested.

It worked, I removed "-i" from container arguments and used: .WithContainerRuntimeArgs("--gpus=all") .WithArgs( "sleep", "infinity"), I will update the question with the complete solution and mark your answer as the correct one with an annotation that the best approach is to avoid to create new process (thank you!)
